# Android Studio gradle build issue: local variable type mismatch

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

As I tried to find solution on internet but nothing too much related to my case

Issue is next, build fails and getting error:
Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a local variable of type int. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.

I have 2 configs

```
buildTypes {
debug {
    debuggable true
    minifyEnabled true
    signingConfig signingConfigs.defaultKey
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}

release {
    debuggable false
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

}

issue is if I turn off debug proguard (minifyEnabled false) I get issue with build

```
Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a local variable of type int. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type int using a local variable of type android.util.SparseIntArray. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
```

Inta-Run is disabled as proguard is enabled

So whatever I do I can't get past this point, even if I create separate proguard file (debug one)
and put next:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-ignorewarnings
```

getting same, tried with : multiDexEnabled true
but still no success
In this case with proguard enabled I can build, getting debug/release normally and all works EXCEPT debug (what I need a lot)

And this is 2nd day in row that I having issue with it and can' solve it
Have somebody have similar issues? How I could solve it?

P.S.
gradle with stacktrace and debug flags gives me nothing useful so no help

Comment: I guess you cannot activate debuggable while also minifying. try to disable minifying and enable debuggable and vis vera

Comment: I have tried both ways and now working :(

Comment: you wrote "now working"? I guess that was a typo then?

Comment: sorry it is typo (auto correct) "not" should be

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from that part you've posted then? Maybe more pieces of the gradle file would be useful

Comment: can't post whole file but here are all my dependencies http://pastebin.com/Y9yXRD0f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are only getting the problem when disabling **ProGuard** in your debug build.

This is an indication that one of your dependent jars has not been built correctly and contains a **LocalVariableTable** or **LocalVariableTypeTable** attribute that is not valid, resulting in the error as shown in the question.

The reason that you do not see the issue when ProGuard is enabled is because ProGuard will remove the relevant attributes by default (unless you add a *-keepattributes xxx* configuration).

To resolve this issue, you will need to identify which jar is responsible for the problem and get a proper version of it (either by processing it yourself with ProGuard to remove the LocalVariable tables or by getting an updated version that is correctly built).

Sometimes the problem is because of a jar that has been optimized by ProGuard. One specific optimization technique is known to have issues, and should be disabled for libraries (*-optimizations !code/allocation/variable*).

Comment: Thanks for explanation, now this issue have more sense
I have added debug gradle - http://pastebin.com/44DAdQbx
and now build 1st time fail (same issue) but strange issue is 2nd time (and any other is working fine)

Answer (score 0):

This happened after I uninstalled Google Repository from SDK Manager, and the problem continued even after I reinstalled it.

I fixed it by closing Android Studio, deleting a bunch of cache-related things from the file system, and then re-opening Android Studio.

Some of the files I deleted were:

- `{USERPROFILE}\.gradle`
- `{project}\build`
- `build`
- `{IDE}\tmp`